# How can I exit "bash"?

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

I don't know how to get my `.profile` aliases back in to the terminal every time I try them, this error massage comes up:

```
apaw:~ apaw$ cdp
-bash: cdp: command not found
```

How do i exit this -bash? I strongly believe it was named different while it still worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found out what the problem was, some script has created a `.bash_profile` file that was overriding my `.profile` file, now I've removed the `.bash_profile` file and it works again!

Comment: I recommend using .bash_profile instead of .profile, especially if it contains any bash-specific code. Also, if you're not already doing it this way: you should generally place customizations in .bashrc and have .bash_profile source .bashrc. .bashrc applies to login and non-login shells, but .profile (and .bash_profile) only apply to login shells.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

The `-bash:` prefix you see is simply bash's way of identifying itself as the source of the error message. In this case you entered `cdp` which is neither an external nor internal shell command nor was it defined as an alias or function.

While in a (bash) terminal, you can simply type `exit` to leave the terminal and close the shell session.

The aliases in your `.profile` are read when you start a new terminal or shell session, or if you `source` the files: e.g. `source ~/.profile`.  That should re-read your `.profile` and load any changed aliases.